# Splunk: How to Write regex for pathparam?

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I have following two API's

```
/rest/customer/{id}
/rest/customer/{id}/account
```

How can i write a spunk query to just get records with first Endpoint?

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly clear what you're asking.

This will extract the id from the string, regardless of account is there or not.

```
rex field=path "/rest/customer/(?<id>[^/]+)"
```

If you want events that don't end in account, you can try

```
where NOT path LIKE "%/account"
```